# If $G$ is a non cyclic group of order 27 find the number of elements $x\in G$ such that $x^9 = e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group.
> If $G$ is a non cyclic group of order $27$ find the number of elements $x\in G$ such that $x^9 = e$.

PD: I cant' use Sylow theorem.

**My attempt**

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element divides $27$. There is exactly one element of order $1$. Then $x$ has order $3,9$ or $27$.

I'm stuck here. Can someone help me?

Comment: it shouldn't be so hard to count the number of order-27 elements

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right track, but $27$ must be ruled out as the group is assumed non cyclic. So, every nontrivial element has order either $3$ or $9$, and in both cases $x^9=e$.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: All $27$ elements $x$ of $G$ satisfy $x^9=e$, or $x^3=e$ or $x=e$ [which would give $x^9=e$ for that $x$ as well].

Let $g$ be any element in $G$. If $g^9$ is not $e$, then the smallest integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$ is $n=27$ [why is that]. But then if $n$ is $27$, then $g$ would generate all of $G$ which would imply that $G$ would be cyclic....